# What is a difference between var app = require(..) and var app = module.exports = require(..)?

Tags: node.js

I have an question about a common usage but difficult for nodejs newbie.

What is a difference between

```
var app = require('./index');
```

and

```
var app = module.exports = require('./index');
```

?

Anything different or is there something I don't know?
Thank you for reading this. :)

Comment: One assigns to `app` and one assigns to `app` and `module.exports`.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: thanks for comments! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = module.exports = require('./index');
```

is the same thing as

```
module.exports = require('./index');
var app = module.exports;
```

Answer (score 2):

`require('./index')` will return (reference) whatever the value of `module.exports`  in `index.js`

Your code in index.js will be wrapped by a `function(exports, module, etc.){}`

So, the difference between your two statements is : in the second statement whatever you assign to app will also be returned to the require

```
var app = module.exports = require('./index'); //assume index returns{ name:'joe' } 
app.age='20;  // now you will return {name:'joe', age:20}
```

now if you require this file you will receive `{name:'joe', age:20}`